# Java: Initialize Array of two ArrayLists in One Line

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

Is it possible to init an Array of two ArrayLists as a class field in Java?

Now I have the following. In the fields declaration:

```
public ArrayList someArray[] = new ArrayList[2];
```

and later in one of methods the actual assigning:

```
someArray[0] = new ArrayList<String>();
someArray[1] = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done! Your code seems correct. Arrays hold only the references of the objects within them, so the objects themselves can be anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done :

```
public ArrayList<String[]>[]
    someArray = new ArrayList[] {new ArrayList<String[]>(),new ArrayList<String[]>()};
```

Edited after clarification from OP.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud What doesn't work? Note it's `new ArrayList[]`, not `new ArrayList<String>[]`, since you can't instantiate an array of a generic type, but it's better practice for the type of the variable itself to be generic.

Comment: If I am correct, that is because you cannot make an array of typed objects. Here, you are trying to do a `ArrayList<String>[]` (in the declaration). It should be reduced to `ArrayList[]` to work, as in [Manu AG's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36761798/1734119). The lost of the generic parameter has always bothered me in this case.

Comment: @Eran well, later in the code I have `someVar[index].add(someArrayOfStrings);` line and it failed.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud if you are trying to add a `String[]` to an `ArrayList<String>`, of course it wouldn't work. I assumed you wanted your `ArrayList`s to contains `String`s, not `String` arrays. You'll have to change the declaration to `public ArrayList<String[]> someArray[] = new ArrayList[] {new ArrayList<String[]>(),new ArrayList<String[]>()};`

Comment: Sorry if I made it unclear, I definitely wanted to store String[] in my inner ArrayLists.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud The `new ArrayList<String>` statements in your question were misleading. I updated the answer to reflect what you want to store in the inner ArrayLists. Note that the JLS strongly discourages the use of raw types. Using generic types lets the compiler prevent you from adding a `String[]` to an `ArrayList<String>` as allowed by Manu's code.

Comment: I tried your updated suggestion, but at first IntelliJ IDEA throws a warning `Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList[]' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]>[]'` and at compile time there is an error `Error:(90, 63) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String[]>` when compiler I try to assign `someArray[0]` some ArrayList of strings.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud I thought you wanted to assign `ArrayList<String[]>` to `someArray[0]`, not `ArrayList<String>`. Isn't that what you said in your previous comment?

Comment: Sure I did. Probably I just messed the code around a little. However, I dropped the idea of such a complex array and stick to my own class, which is more convenient in my case. Your answer is indeed is "more proper" than other, so I "Accepted" it now instead of @Manu AG's. Thanks for useful input regarding the raw types.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public ArrayList[] arrayOfArrayLists = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList<String>() , new ArrayList<String>()};
```

Comment: Using raw types is strongly discouraged, as stated in the JLS - `The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.`